# Apach POI how to merge Word cells vertivally?

Tags: apache-poi

I have Apache POI Word table with six columns and need to merge vertically cells in first three columns. Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219092/how-to-horizontally-merge-xwpftable-using-poi-in-java/49222078#49222078

Comment: Thank you, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41174828/1999752 looks like mo relevant